# How to execute programs in the same directory as the windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, relative-path

I have in the same folder a `.bat` and a `.exe` file.
I couldn't call the `.exe` file from the `.bat` unless I put the full absolute path to it.
Is there a way to don't specify the path?

Comment: FYI: you couldn’t run `a.cmd` or `.\\a.cmd` because the current working directory of the shell was not the batch file’s directory.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Try calling the `.exe` with `%~dp0`, like this: `%~dp0MyProgram.exe`.

`%0` contains the full path to the called `.bat` file.

`~dp` says to get the drive and path, including trailing `\`.

Comment: +1 vote

just found this link on google search - http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/01/28/get-directory-path-of-an-executing-batch-file.aspx

Comment: Patrick Cuff's answer above works, but fails if part of the directory path has spaces in its name. To get around this you need to put double quotes around the .exe call. "%~dp0MyProgram.exe"

Comment: To add to this answer, if you change your execution path to the current directory as follows: `cd "%~dp0"` you can just call MyProgram.exe just like that

Answer (score 35):

I solved this by changing the working directory using [pushd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490978.aspx) at the start of the script and restoring is at the end of the script using [popd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490969.aspx). This way you can always assume the working directory is the same as the location of the bat file.

```
pushd %~dp0
ProgramInSameFolderAsBat.exe
popd
```

Comment: Note that changing working directory could have side-effects within the executed file/script. In my case, I needed the working directory to remain as it was. @Patrick Cuff's answer worked in consideration of that

Comment: This code works best! I would add `set workpath=%cd%` before `pushd %~dp0` to keep a reference to the working path which then can be passed to the .exe if needed 
like that `ProgramInSameFolderAsBat.exe -workingpath "%workpath%" %*`

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen C said, to properly support paths with spaces we can use:

`start "%~dp0" "myfile.exe"`

or with arguments:

`start "%~dp0" "myfile.exe" -my_arguments`