# Executing the .msi from batch file in same location

Tags: batch-file

We need to run a .msi file from batch file which is working fine if the path of .msi file is hard coded in batch file. Is there any way to get the path of .msi file dynamically as the batch file and .msi file exist at same folder location? It will really solve the purpose as thses needs to be copied to multiple servers...

Comment: the below link helped:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730643/how-to-execute-programs-in-the-same-directory-as-the-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%~dp0install.msi
```

%~dp0 gives you the path of your bat-file.
(note, that the last backslash is already included.

try `@echo %~dp0` in your batch-file)

Comment: What if i need to add a log.txt file to same location?

Comment: `echo I want to log this line >>%~dp0log.txt` or better: `set logfile=%~dp0log.txt` in the beginning of your batchfile and later `echo whatever I want to say >>%logfile%`

Comment: +1 for %~dp0.  In addition of that, you can use `PUSHD %~dp0` at the beginning of your script and `POPD` at the end of the script to set the current directory to the location of you script ONLY for the duration of the script.  I use it all the time.

Comment: Some of the documentation for the `%~dpX` format is at the tail end of `for /?`.  They're pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

If the batch file and msi file are in the same folder then no path at all is needed.  The batch file defaults to the current directory - and will write the log file to the current directory.

This is only an issue if the batch file is launched from a network drive.